# What does "a-crowding" mean in the following verse

Tags: meaning

From "O Captain! My Captain!" by Walt Whitman:

> O Captain! my Captain! rise up and hear the bells;
>
> Rise up—for you the flag is flung—for you the bugle trills,
>
> **For you bouquets and ribbon’d wreaths—for you the shores a-crowding,**
>
> For you they call, the swaying mass, their eager faces turning;

While I cannot recall any concrete examples at the moment, I do remember encountering the prefix "a-" in poetry a couple of times before. Can anyone explain what it is all about?

Comment: Add the syllable to make the meter come out right.  Actually, "a(verb)ing" was quite common in the past.

Answer (score 4):

This [a- prefix](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/a-) was derived from Old English, a time when there was a lot more inflection (see also [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=bUoSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT186&lpg=PT186)).

With a verb, it's called *a-verbing*. You can actually just ignore the prefix and treat it as a regular gerund:

> for you the shores [are] crowding

---

See also:

- [a-verbing (grammar)](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/averbingterm.htm)
- [My answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/111547/41273) to the question [Words that are a combination of 'a'+word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/111489/41273)
- [When he fain would be on the bough <a-swing>](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/105939/41273)
- [The pattern *to be a-hunting* from Middle  to Late Modern English](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zv8XBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT67)